# Actionscript 3 dynamic text automatically scroll to the very bottom

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

How can I automatically scroll down the to very bottom of a dynamic textbox?

Thanks

Comment: do you mean a Flash TextArea component (fl.controls.TextArea)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for textfield it's something like `myText.scrollV = myText.maxScrollV`